# Look For Ten Using PHP Programming Language

Tags: php

[image]I am trying to write a program to create a function that takes two arguments. Both arguments are integers, a and b. And it will return true if one of them is 10 or if their sum is 10. And I am doing it on "Codemama" platform. The numbers are given on the console area in codemama platform and the output is not showing as expected. Do I have to call "lookForTen" function? Because if I have to then I have to pass the arguments after calling the function. But as I said it's already available in the console. And the output is supposed to be "true" but it's not showing anything Here's the code below. Please help me find the mistake.

```
<?php
    # Write your PHP code from here

    $a = trim(fgets(STDIN)); 
    $b = trim(fgets(STDIN));


function lookForTen($a, $b):bool{

    if($a + $b == 10){

        return true;
        
    }
    
    else{

        return false;
        
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Plz add the code!

Comment: <?php
    # Write your PHP code from here

    $a = trim(fgets(STDIN)); 
    $b = trim(fgets(STDIN));


function lookForTen($a, $b):bool{

    if($a + $b == 10){

        return true;
        
    }
    
    else{

        return false;
        
    }
}

?>

Comment: It should be `return  $a + $b == 10 || in_array(10, [$a, $b])`

Comment: In the above the `lookForTen` function does not get called so it is unclear how you expect it to work

Comment: You could simplify your function to `function lookForTen( $a=0, $b=0 ){ return $a==10 or $b==10 or $a+$b==10; }`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Sorry for not clearly stating my problem. I have shared a screenshot of the problem which I am facing.

Comment: but you have not called the PHP function - at least not in the code you posted above. We cannot test your code with a screenshot either - you need to call the function, like `lookForTen($a,$b) ? 'true' : 'false'` or similar

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It helped me a lot.